# Error of source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

Tags: java, scala, maven

I use scala-maven-plugin to compile a project with both scala and java code. I already set the source and target to 1.7, but not sure why maven still use 1.5.

Here's my plugin in pom.xml

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>eclipse-add-source</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-scaladocs</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>doc-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
          <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
          <args>
            <arg>-unchecked</arg>
            <arg>-deprecation</arg>
            <arg>-feature</arg>
          </args>
          <jvmArgs>
            <jvmArg>-Xms1024m</jvmArg>
            <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
            <jvmArg>-XX:PermSize=${PermGen}</jvmArg>
            <jvmArg>-XX:MaxPermSize=${MaxPermGen}</jvmArg>
          </jvmArgs>
          <javacArgs>
            <javacArg>-source</javacArg>
            <javacArg>1.7</javacArg>
            <javacArg>-target</javacArg>
            <javacArg>1.7</javacArg>
            <javacArg>-Xlint:all,-serial,-path,-options</javacArg>
          </javacArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

And this the output error I see

```
[warn]   implicit def toDisplayTraversableFunctions[T <: Product](traversable: Traversable[T]): DisplayTraversableFunctions[T] = new DisplayTraversableFunctions[T](traversable)
[warn]                ^
[warn] two warnings found
[error] /Users/jzhang/github/zeppelin/spark/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/spark/DepInterpreter.java:158: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[error]     settings.explicitParentLoader_$eq(new Some<>(Thread.currentThread()
```

But I am sure I am usign JDK8.

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Maven also use JDK8

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024M; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /Users/jzhang/Java/lib/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: Are you sure that maven is using the "right" java compiler ? How do you launch maven ? What is the output if you run the command `java -version` ?

Comment: I use JDK 8. Here's output of `java -version` java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: I know that it is a silly question, but what is the output of `mvn -v` ? You could launch maven with the debug flag (mvn -X) in the attempt to collect more information on the scala plugin behaviour.

Comment: maven also use jdk8. updated the description.

Comment: You should probably run with a mvn -x and although it is very verbose, it will give you a lot of useful information. Which maven plugin is actually running here. I think you have scala compile first, then a regular java compile (with 1.5) and hence the failure. If so, the plugin executed when erroring would be the maven-compile-plugin and not the maven-scala-plugin.

Answer (score 4):

The quintessential way to set the compiler source and target versions these days seems to be use these pre-defined properties:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

As you already noted, these default to `1.5` in maven. This is because Maven was always about "convention over configuration" and this default value was defined when Java 1.5 was still shiny and new. Unfortunately this has been difficult to change because any existing projects that still depend on Java 1.5 (and had not specified these values) could break.

Comment: So... those projects have the latest Maven, but still Java 1.5? Way to go, guys! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maven by default will install Java 1.5 compiler. You need to specifically assign Java 1.8 in the `pom.xml` file. Since Maven is nothing but a combination of various plugins, we need to add the compiler plugin and specify the Java compiler version by adding the following snippet:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```