# Servlet Error: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Trying to create web service for verifying login however there is an error of try without catch without having a try in the code.

The error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
'try' without 'catch' or 'finally'

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
illegal start of type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
illegal start of type

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
';' expected

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
<identifier> expected

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
<identifier> expected

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
class, interface, or enum expected
```

The login form

```
        <form action="loginServlet" method="post">
            Login ID:
            <input type="text" name="loginid"/>
            <br>
            Password:
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login">
            <input type="reset" name="btnReset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

The servlet to process the login verification, I have tried not using the servlet and just go directly to the link manually by typing and it does return the JSON that I want to retrieve.

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          String userid =request.getParameter("loginid");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("--------------"+userid);
              Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
             String url="http://localhost:8080/Onlineshop/app/onlineshop";
        WebTarget target = client
                .target(url)
                .path("verifyUser")
                .queryParam("loginid", userid)
                .queryParam("password", password);
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Response res = invocationBuilder.get();
        if (res.getStatus() == 200){
            User userdata = res.readEntity(User.class);

            request.setAttribute("user", userdata.getUserid());
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("displaydetails.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

If the code in other class is needed please tell me. Thank you for the help

Comment: which version of java you are using? is this maven project?Which server you are deploying this application?

Comment: You are getting the error `target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release`, and apart from any other issues, you probably want to set your Java version appropriately in **pom.xml**. You are probably getting that error because the default Java version used by Maven is 1.5. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48794564/2985643) for details on how to specify your version of Java. Also, update the question once you have done that, since that might also resolve some of your other errors.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not familiar with Maven, and how do I access pom.xml? because i could only see  persistence.xml and web.xml. I am using mysql, glassfish server and restful web services. Edit: When i created the project, I chose Java Web -> Web Application

Comment: OK, my mistake. In that case you have created an Ant application within NetBeans, so to resolve the issue: [1] Select your project in the **Projects** panel, right click and then select **Properties** from the context menu. [2] In the **Properties** window go to **Libraries > Java Platform** and ensure the appropriate version of Java you want to use is selected in the drop list. [3] Go to **Sources > Source/Binary Format** and select that same version of Java. [4] Click **OK** and rebuild your project.

Comment: I am sorry but I found out the error and it is a dumb error, I have an extra closing bracket in my Jsp but it shows obsolete as the error. Once I removed it, the project went successfully. Should I flag this thread?